# Tkinter canvas leave event isn't trigged

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I would have rectangle orange filled on the Leave event, but when I Leave on the rectangle to Enter in other rectangle, sometime the leave event isn't trigged.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

ENTER = '7'
LEAVE = '8'

def change_color_on_enter_or_leave(event):
    canvas = event.widget
    item_ids = canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
    for item_id in item_ids:
        if event.type == ENTER:
            canvas.itemconfig(item_id, fill="orange")
        elif event.type == LEAVE:
            canvas.itemconfig(item_id, fill="red")

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, background="white")
label = Label(root)

for x in range(0, 200, 50):
    for y in range(0, 200, 50):
        canvas.create_rectangle((x, y), (x + 40, y + 40), fill='red', tag='rectangle')

canvas.tag_bind('rectangle', '<Enter>', change_color_on_enter_or_leave)
canvas.tag_bind('rectangle', '<Leave>', change_color_on_enter_or_leave)

canvas.grid()
label.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: probably when you move too fast tkinter doesn't see that mouse left one rectangle and entered another rectangle :/ You could add different tags to every rectangle - maybe to helps.

Comment: btw: maybe you should use `grid()` with buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign to every rectangle unique tag and then use `lambda` to send this tag to function

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

ENTER = '7'
LEAVE = '8'

# extra argument - unique tag
def change_color_on_enter_or_leave(event, tag):

    canvas = event.widget

    # find by tag
    item_ids = canvas.find_withtag(tag)

    for item_id in item_ids:
        if event.type == ENTER:
            canvas.itemconfig(item_id, fill="orange")
        elif event.type == LEAVE:
            canvas.itemconfig(item_id, fill="red")



root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, background="white")
label = Label(root)

for x in range(0, 200, 50):
    for y in range(0, 200, 50):

        # create unique tag
        tag = 'rectangle_%s_%s' % (x,y)
        canvas.create_rectangle((x, y), (x + 40, y + 40), fill='red', tag=tag)

        # use unique tag in function
        canvas.tag_bind(tag, '<Enter>', lambda event,t=tag:change_color_on_enter_or_leave(event,t))
        canvas.tag_bind(tag, '<Leave>', lambda event,t=tag:change_color_on_enter_or_leave(event,t))

canvas.grid()
label.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** `create_rectangle()` returns unique ID so you can use it instead of unique tag.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

ENTER = '7'
LEAVE = '8'

# extra argument - rectangle ID
def change_color_on_enter_or_leave(event, r_id):

    canvas = event.widget

    # you don't have to search IDs

    if event.type == ENTER:
        canvas.itemconfig(r_id, fill="orange")
    elif event.type == LEAVE:
        canvas.itemconfig(r_id, fill="red")

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, background="white")
label = Label(root)

for x in range(0, 200, 50):
    for y in range(0, 200, 50):

        # get rectangle ID
        r_id = canvas.create_rectangle((x, y), (x + 40, y + 40), fill='red', tag='rectangle') # tag "rectangle" use for something different

        # use rectangle ID with function
        canvas.tag_bind(r_id, '<Enter>', lambda event,t=r_id:change_color_on_enter_or_leave(event,t))
        canvas.tag_bind(r_id, '<Leave>', lambda event,t=r_id:change_color_on_enter_or_leave(event,t))

canvas.grid()
label.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I use canvas.find_withtag('rectangle') in order to return all id.

Comment: if you need all ID then you can still assign tag `rectangle` in `create_rectangle` and use `r_id` to bind `<Enter>` and `<Leave>`